# Grouping of regex with same name

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I am trying to write a regex to get the ingredients name, quantity, unit from the sting. The string can be any pattern like "pohe 2 kg OR 2 Kg pohe OR 2Kg Pohe".
I have tried with below code -

```
<?PHP
    $units = array("tbsp", "ml", "g", "grams", "kg", "few drops"); // add whatever other units are allowed
  
    
    //mixed pattern
    $pattern = '/(?J)(((?<i>^[a-zA-Z\s]+)(?<q>\d*\s*)(?<u>' . join("|", array_map("preg_quote", $units)) . '))|(?<q>^\d*\s*)(?<u>' . join("|", array_map("preg_quote", $units)) . ')(?<i>[a-zA-Z\s]+))/';

    
    $ingredients = '2kg pohe';
    
    preg_match_all($pattern, $ingredients, $m);
    print_r($m);
    $quantities = $m['q'];
    $units = array_map('trim', $m['u']);
    $ingrd = array_map('trim', $m['i']);
    print_r($quantities);
    print_r($units);
    print_r($ingrd);
?>
```

The above code works for the string "2kg pohe", but not for the "pohe 2kg".

If anyone having idea what I am missing, please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `pohe 2kg` duplicate named groups are empty, as the documentation of `preg_match_all` states that for the flag [PREG_PATTERN_ORDER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) (which is the default)

> If the pattern contains duplicate named subpatterns, only the
> rightmost subpattern is stored in $matches[NAME].

Int he pattern that you generate, there is a match in the second part (after the alternation) for `2kg pohe` but for the `pohe 2kg` there is only a match in the first part so for the second part there are no values stored.

What you might do, is use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag instead, which gives:

```
$ingredients = '2kg pohe';
preg_match_all($pattern, $ingredients, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2kg pohe
    [i] =>  pohe
    [1] => 
    [q] => 2
    [2] => 
    [u] => kg
    [3] => 
    [4] => 2
    [5] => kg
    [6] =>  pohe
)
```

And

```
$ingredients = 'pohe 2kg';
preg_match_all($pattern, $ingredients, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => pohe 2kg
    [i] => pohe 
    [1] => pohe 
    [q] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [u] => kg
    [3] => kg
)
```

Then you can get the named subgroups for both strings like `$m[0]['i']` etc..

**Note** that in the example there is `2Kg` and you can make the pattern case insensitive to match.

Comment: Thanks for help .This same thing I am trying to do in the js. but its not working .
Please find the below code for same.
```
let pattern = /((?<ingre>^[a-zA-Z ]+)(?<quantity>[0-9 ]*)(?<unit>kg|g)|((?<quantity>[0-9 ]*)(?<unit>kg|g)(?<ingre>^[a-zA-Z ]+)))/g

let str = "pohe 2kg"
let results = str.matchAll(pattern);
for(let result of results) {
  let {ingre, quantity, unit} = result.groups;

  alert(`${ingre}.${quantity}.${unit}`);

}
```
This shows error as Duplicate capture group name
Not getting which modifier works for this in js regex

Comment: @sonalibhat I think Javascript does not support duplicate group names. In that case you can omit the group names, and check for the group numbers if they have a value or not, as you know which number corresponds to which value type.

Comment: Can you please share the example code on the same which I have provided? It will be really helpful for me

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have accepted your answer but couldn't upvote your answer as don't have upvote rights.